# How to call external javascript on window.load?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put this in my website

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- window.onload = hello; function
hello() { var name = prompt("What is your name", "") alert ( "Hello "
+ name + "! Welcome to my forum.") } </script>
```

but I dont want to put it in index but in separate file, let say hello.js

How can I call it from index file so when I click the index.html, it will immediately prompt for my name. (for example)

I put `<script src="hello.js"></script>` does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your hello.js should look something like this:

```
window.onload = hello; 

function hello() { 
    var name = prompt("What is your name", "");
    alert("Hello " + name + "! Welcome to my forum."); 
}
```

and then the `<script src="hello.js"></script>` should work just fine.

Comment: @Wan- so the issue was with comment tag added by you.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be much more to it than importing that script. But then, your script is all broken. Of course it won't work, unless your browser can interpret it. Take a look at javascript basics. On the first look, you don't seem to be using semicolons to delimit individual statements. Also, you have opened an HTML comment `<!--` but you have never closed it...

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var name = prompt("What is your name", "");
alert ( "Hello " + name + "! Welcome to my forum.");  </script>
```

i.e, remove any function and just write your alert directly, this should work.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu Server 16.04

external JS

change-from: --> window.onload = hello;

change-to: --> window.document.body.onload = hello;

html

body onload="hello()"

Comment: sorry first post and this interface is still new

Comment: Welcome to SO. Be aware that you answered a 4 year old post. As for answering please read [answer]